# Hardhat deploy same contract to multiple addresses fails

Tags: hardhat, solidity-0.8.x, hardhat-deploy, sepolia

I need to deploy the same contract to multiple wallets and I have this shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
contractName=MyContract
network=sepolia
npm cache clean --force
yarn hardhat clean
yarn hardhat compile
yarn hardhat deploy --network "$network" --tags "$contractName"
yarn hardhat etherscan-verify --network "$network"
```

Then in my `hardhat.config.ts` I have

```
import "hardhat-deploy";
import "hardhat-deploy-ethers";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle";
import "@typechain/hardhat";
import "hardhat-gas-reporter";
import "solidity-coverage";
import { resolve } from "path";
import { config as dotenvConfig } from "dotenv";
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/types";
import { Wallet } from "ethers";

dotenvConfig({ path: resolve(__dirname, "./.env") });

const deployerKey: string = process.env.DEPLOYER_PRIV_KEY || "";
const deployerWallet = new Wallet(deployerKey);

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
      default: deployerWallet.address,
    },
  },
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 1337,
      allowBlocksWithSameTimestamp: false,
      gas: 8000000,
      forking: {
        url: "https://rpc.ankr.com/eth", // Fork mainnet for testing
        blockNumber: 17396037, // Comment this line if you want to test with latest block
      },
      mining: {
        auto: true,
        interval: 0,
      },
    },
    eth: {
      accounts: [deployerKey],
      chainId: 1,
      url: `https://rpc.ankr.com/eth`,
      verify: {
        etherscan: {
          apiKey: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY || "",
        },
      },
    },
    sepolia: {
      accounts: [deployerKey],
      chainId: 11155111,
      url: `https://rpc.ankr.com/eth_sepolia`,
      verify: {
        etherscan: {
          apiKey: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY || "",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  solidity: "0.8.18",
};
console.log("deployerWallet.address: "+deployerWallet.address)//<--I can see different addresses
export default config;
```

And finally my `deploy.ts`

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";

async function main() {
  const currentTimestampInSeconds = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
  const unlockTime = currentTimestampInSeconds + 1;//60

  const lockedAmount = ethers.parseEther("0.001");

  const lock = await ethers.deployContract("Lock", [unlockTime], {
    value: lockedAmount,
  });

  await lock.waitForDeployment();

  console.log(
    `Lock with ${ethers.formatEther(
      lockedAmount
    )}ETH and unlock timestamp ${unlockTime} deployed to ${lock.target}`
  );
}

// We recommend this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere
// and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

When I change the DEPLOYER_PRIV_KEY in the .env I can see that in the console but I don't get a new contract I get:

```
already verified: MyContract (0x...), skipping.
```

How can I modify the code to force the contract to be deployed to a new address?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the new contract is deployed, but because of same the bytecode it already gets verified before you run the verification command,  can you check/share your wallet address and see if the transactions went through or not.